# Why does Register-SitecoreInstallExtension appear to do nothing?

Tags: powershell, sitecore-install-framework

I'm making my first attempt at extending SIF, and I don't seem to be able to register a new Task correctly. Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong here?

I've create a new script commandlet. It has the following contents:

```
function Invoke-SolrInstallTask
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$solrVersion = "6.6.2",

        #
        # more declarations
        #
    )

    PROCESS
    {
        #
        # Code for the task...
        #
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Invoke-SolrInstallTask
```

That file is saved as `Invoke-SolrInstallTask.psm1` in my user's module folder at

```
C:\Users\<myUser>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Invoke-SolrInstallTask\
```

Calling

```
Import-Module Invoke-SolrInstallTask
```

appears to work, and a subsequent call to `Get-Module` shows that PowerShell has registered my function as a script:

[image: Result of Get-Module]

If I try to run my commandlet directly it appears to work ok. So then I call:

```
Register-SitecoreInstallExtension Invoke-SolrInstallTask -As SolrInstall -Type Task
```

That generates no output.

I can see from the SIF that documentation that `Get-SitecoreInstallExtension` only returns references to standard tasks, unless you call it passing a configuration file.

My `solr.json` config file contains (amongst other stuff) a block that tries to use the custom task:

```
"Tasks" : {
    "PerformSolrInstall": {
        "Type": "SolrInstall",
        "Params": {
            "solrVersion": "[parameter('SolrVersion')]"
        }
    }
}
```

But despite that `Get-SitecoreInstallExtension .\solr.json` never returns any reference to my task:

[image: Result of Get-SitecoreInstallExtension]

And unsurprisingly, if I try to run that custom config I get an error:

[image: SIF error message]

I'm guessing there's some other bit of "how to register a custom task" that I've failed to find in the documentation. Any suggestions what it is?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a small thing which I'm hoping to have fixed soon so that things are a little clearer, sorry this isn't as straight-forward as it should be!

Calling `Register-SitecoreInstallExtension` outside of a running install does nothing as there is no context for it to operate in.  The function actually sets information in a dictionary when the install itself imports the function.

I'll be addressing this in the next release by outputting an appropriate message rather than silence.

To actually enable functions to be registered correctly do the following:

1. Create your psm1 file (e.g. MySifExtensions.psm1)
2. For *each* function in there that you want SIF to use, call `Register-SitecoreInstallExtension` *in the psm1*
3. In the configuration, include the path to the module

So your `MySifExtension.psm1` looks like this

```powershell
function Invoke-SolrInstallTask{ <# implementation #> }
Register-SitecoreInstallExtension -Command Invoke-SolrInstallTask -As SolrInstall -Type Task
```

Then in your configuration file:

```
"Parameters" : {},
"Variables": {},
"Tasks": {},
"Modules" : [
  'path to module'
]
```

With the module path, either specify the full path or the path relative to the configuration file.  If the module is available by name when calling `Import-Module` you can specify just the name of the module.

You can get embedded help on the topic of extending by running:

```powershell
Get-help about_SitecoreInstallFramework_Extending -ShowWindow
```

Alternatively, check out the documentation on configuring and extending sif here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/90/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_90_Initial_Release.aspx#

Comment: Ah - thank you - I knew there was something I missed.
Working now...